# How can I create a new package in Intellij 2018 2.2?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Hi I just got started using Intellij version 2018.2.2 and unlike some older tutorials when I right click on the directory under the Project tab ( on the RHS) and click New I do not see an option to create a new package, but however there is option to create a new Java class.

Is there a way to create packages on the IntelliJ IDE? For now I tried dragging the java classes onto each other which allows me to create a new package but I was wondering if there could be any other way to create new packages.

Comment: Creating a class creates the package as well. See [Create your first Java application - Help | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html)